# Text to speech Raspberry pi error - gtts.tts.gTTSError: Connection error during token calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am writing a code to convert some english language lines in the file "questions.txt" to speech via google text-to-speech on a Raspberry Pi 3.
I am using the gTTS library of Python to do the above. But my code returns the following error

```
Starting Conversion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tts.py", line 21, in <module>
    getAudioQues()
  File "tts.py", line 16, in getAudioQues
    myobj.save("../data/quesAudio/"+str(quesNo)+".mp3")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 247,       in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 192,  in write_to_fp
    str(e))
gtts.tts.gTTSError: Connection error during token calculation:   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded  with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

My code is as follows:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

language = 'en'
def getAudioQues():
    quesNo=1
    f=open("../data/questions.txt","r")
    f1=f.readlines()
    print "Starting Conversion"
    os.mkdir("../data/quesAudio")
    for x in f1: 
        mytext = x

        myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)

        myobj.save("../data/quesAudio/"+str(quesNo)+".mp3")
        quesNo+=1

    f.close()

getAudioQues()
```

Comment: what is the version of gtts-token. it should be 1.1.2. check the  version of gtts-token using pip freeze